# installing Anaconda, errno 2 no such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I've taken a look at some of the other AskUbuntus, and none of them have fixed my problem. I've been running iPython for almost six months now in order to get some extra practice with the Codecademy Python tutorial. I just completed the last lesson, and am now trying to install Anaconda in order to start learning data analysis tools, plotting, etc., because I hear that Anaconda has a ton of great libraries suited for my uses.

I'm a novice Linux user; I know how to change directories, make directories, and I can assure you my terminal says I'm in u/'home', which is where the Anaconda download from Continuum resides. (That's just to give you an idea of what kind of basic-level assistance I'll be needing, since I haven't been able to Google my way out of this one.)

The crux of the story:  when I navigate to the home folder, and type

> bash Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

in the terminal, (just like Continuum tells me to) I'm told that I either have invalid syntax, and it points to the a at the end of 'Anaconda', or it tells me that there is "No such file or directory"

Which is sub-optimal, because when I open up the home folder, there it is, Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh, sitting there, mocking me in its disuse.

Your assistance is greatly desired. Thank you in advance.

Daniel

Comment: If you type "bash Ana" and press Tab is it completed to the full file name? You do have a 64 bit system, right?

Comment: It says I don't have a 64 bit system, that may have been the problem. Also, since I already have python installed, I'm just going to install the numpy and matplotlib separately.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that installer, but I had similar issues in other cases where I accidentally tried to start 32bit binaries on a 64 bit system. The resulting file not found error message is not particularly enlightening in that case.

Comment: should I have a 64 bit system?

Comment: Uhm, if your computer isn't very old, your hardware is very probably 64bit capable. It doesn't make much sense to install a 32 bit OS then.

Comment: Hinz, I got it to work, finally. Just haven't logged on here in a while. You were right about the 64/32 bit thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing initially. I inadvertently downloaded the Power8 version and got the same message. I use Linux Mint. I had to choose the 64 bit x86 installer above it. If you cut and paste the command and choose the Power8 installer, the filenames are actually different which is why the command errors out.